# RC differentiator / RC integrator explanation (input waveform is square wave, triangular wave, sine wave)

Tags: circuit-analysis, filter, low-pass, differential-amplifier, high-pass-filter

The circuit below is an RC differentiator (RC high pass filter.)

[image]

The input and output waveforms:

[image]

I can understand this. Mainly due to capictor charging and discharging.

How about an RC integrator (low pass filter)?

[image]

[image]

For the input waveforms triangular wave and sine wave, what is the shape of the output waveform?

[image]

Comment: [Duplicate](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/635759/95619) (at least partly).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen Thank you. Still difficult to visualise using simple English.

Answer (score 1):

If you understood the differentiator output (you said you did) then maybe this will help: -

[image]

In other words, they are both the same circuit but with different reference points on their nodes so, what you get as an output in the lower circuit, you get in the upper circuit minus the input voltage. That should be fairly easy to visualize.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry, I am still unable to visualize it especially for input is triangular waveform